# prepared statement is not working for SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

When I'm using SQL select statements with prepared statements code works fine and display content when I'm run that in my computer localhost using WAMP server.

But when I'm upload this code to my web hosting. No any result display or no any error display.But without prepared statement code works fine in the web hosting and display results. here is my codes with and without prepared statements. Please tell me why that happens?

**Here is my code:**

```
<?php 

for($i=0;$i <$count; $i++){

    require('connection.php');
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE status = 'Approved' limit 1 offset ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $result = $stmt->get_result();                                          

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()){                          

        $pst_content = $row['content'];
        $author = $row['commentator'];

        if($i==0){

            echo '<div class="item active">';
            echo '      <blockquote>';
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';
            echo "      <p style='color:#a07936'>$pst_content</p>";
            echo "<small>$author</small>";
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </blockquote>';
            echo '      </div>';

        }else{

            echo '<div class="item">';
            echo '      <blockquote>';
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';
            echo "      <p style='color:#a07936'>$pst_content</p>";
            echo "<small>$author</small>";
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </blockquote>';
            echo '      </div>';                                    
        }

    }
    }
}         
?>
```

Comment: Don't use `require` inside a loop. Otherwise, use `require_once` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code according to Procedural style.Your table column as follows? commentator ,Content? then,

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

for($i=0;$i <$count; $i++){

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT commentator,content FROM comment WHERE status = 'Approved' limit 1 offset ?")) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $i);

        /* execute query */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* bind result variables */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$cmnt,$cont);

        /* fetch value */
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        $pst_content = $cont;
        $author = $cmnt;

        if($i==0){

            echo '<div class="item active">';
            echo '      <blockquote>';
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';
            echo "      <p style='color:#a07936'>$pst_content</p>";
            echo "<small>$author</small>";
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </blockquote>';
            echo '      </div>';

        }else{

            echo '<div class="item">';
            echo '      <blockquote>';
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';
            echo "      <p style='color:#a07936'>$pst_content</p>";
            echo "<small>$author</small>";
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </div>';
            echo '      </blockquote>';
            echo '      </div>';                                    
        }       



        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**Read this:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
```

You are trying to bind $id to "s", but you are using a ? in your query.

try

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE status = 'Approved' limit 1 offset ?");
$stmt->bind_param(1, $id);
```

or better

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE status = 'Approved' limit 1 offset :id");
$stmt->bind_param(':id', $id);
```

Comment: I try this one,but this error occur ` Call to a member function bind_param() ` line `$stmt->bind_param(':id', $id);
`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `bind_param()` with a named parameter, it should also be named in the query :

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE status = 'Approved' limit 1 offset :s");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
```

Of course your $id variable should be defined and hold a meaningful value for the offset clause.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object ` I tried this one.this error occur in this line `$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);`

Comment: You should very much follow @Manav advice in the comment above. And check the connection.php file, something might be going wrong in there for that error to show up.